# Port Forwaring to a Linux KVM Guest

Tags: linux, router, port-forwarding, iptables

I have a setup where I run PopOS and and Run Windows 10 in KVM for my games. I recently experienced disconnects from COD:MW due a Strict NAT Type, the web suggest to forward some ports in your router for the game and that should give you a Open NAT type. I have done this befofre if I Ran only Windows (Native, no KVM), but now I am having some trouble doing it when the game is running on a KVM instance.

My Routers has all the portsd that should be forwarded set to forward to the the IP of my Physical NIC that my Linux machince uses. My linux PopOS machine has a IP of 192.168.0.106, abd tge the IP of the Windows instance is 192.168.122.216, So I tried running this for all the ports needed to be forwarded: 
`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3074 -d 192.168.122.216 -j ACCEPT`

This still had no effect on the NAT Type.

I Have a suspicion that this will not work, but what else can I do to forward ports for this Windows Machine and is the Linux isntance even suppose to forward the ports?

Answer (score 1):

The rule you used, was done on the *filter* table. It's intended to allow traffic in case something else (like a default DROP policy) wouldn't else. So depending on your setup this rule might still be needed.

What you actually have to do is exactly what your home router is doing: DNAT (NAT done on the destination part of the packets). This is done in the *nat* table and the PREROUTING chain and will affect all further packets of the same connection. As this is done before the routing decision, the routing stack will only see the new destination, which is not the host anymore, but to be routed to the Windows VM's address. Here's the likely command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3074 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.216
```

You should provide one for each port (and protocol tcp or udp) you already had to "port forward" on your router, to do exactly the same it's doing, one step further: to the VM.